# `new Map()` быстрее объектов и массивов

Tags: javascript

### вопрос/ы касательно объекта `Map()` и его производительности

1. у меня мап `Map int key get took:` **64** против **5610**                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             это:

   1. ошибка теста
   2. так и есть
   3. хитрый хром жульничает, в реалиях оно не так
   4. это ответ хрома на шустрые массивы лиса ?
2. почему так ?
3. так ли быстр мап с объектами, функциями, и т.д. ?
4. когда мап не стоит использовать ? (в контексте производительности)

### предыстория

задался я вопросом, какова производительность `Map` и методом гугления сразу наткнулся на вот такой [gist](https://gist.github.com/jung-kim/83676b2310c7c2a9c3d8) с кодом теста и результатами, в которых мап был раза в два-три шустрее объектов и массивов. думаю: дай-ка и я попробую запустить тест. и вот что получилось у меня:

### результаты теста

браузер chrome(68.0)

```
START
Map int key set took:  1198
Obj int key set took:  5177
ray int key set took:  6113

Map int key get took:  64
Obj int key get took:  5610
ray int key get took:  5044


Map string key set took:  3614
Obj string key set took:  6296
ray string key set took:  8691

Map string key get took:  8126
Obj string key get took:  7608
ray string key get took:  6828

END
```

$ node -v
v10.1.0

```
Map int key set took:  1208
Obj int key set took:  3516
ray int key set took:  3567

Map int key get took:  37
Obj int key get took:  2252
ray int key get took:  2018



Map string key set took:  2444
Obj string key set took:  3925
ray string key set took:  3398

Map string key get took:  712
Obj string key get took:  1706
ray string key get took:  2311
```

---

### код для запуска

(мобильная версия СО не отображает snippet'ы)

```js
function TEST(/*this: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope*/)
{
 console.log = (...mess) => this.postMessage(mess)
 console.log('START\n')

 var indexes = [];
 {
  let n = 2000000;
  while (n > 0)
  {
   indexes.push(Math.random() * 2000000);
   n--;
  }
 }

 let looper = (callback) =>
 {
  let n = 2000000;
  while (n > 0)
  {
   callback(indexes[n], n);
   n--;
  }
 }

 let timer = (mess, callback) =>
 {
  let start = Date.now();
  callback()
  console.log(mess, Date.now() - start);
 }

 {//#region test int
  let map = new Map();
  let obj = {};
  let ray = [];

  timer('Map int key set took: ', () => looper((key, index) => map.set(key, index)));
  timer('Obj int key set took: ', () => looper((key, index) => obj[key] = index));
  timer('ray int key set took: ', () => looper((key, index) => ray[key] = index));
  console.log(' ');
  timer('Map int key get took: ', () => looper((key, index) => { let dummylet = map.get(key); dummylet; }));
  timer('Obj int key get took: ', () => looper((key, index) => { let dummylet = obj[key]; dummylet; }));
  timer('ray int key get took: ', () => looper((key, index) => { let dummylet = ray[key]; dummylet; }));
 }//#endregion

 console.log('\n\n');

 {//#region test string
  let map = new Map();
  let obj = {};
  let ray = [];

  timer('Map string key set took: ', () => looper((key, index) => map.set('' + key, '' + index)));
  timer('Obj string key set took: ', () => looper((key, index) => obj['' + key] = '' + index));
  timer('ray string key set took: ', () => looper((key, index) => ray['' + key] = '' + index));
  console.log(' ');
  timer('Map string key get took: ', () => looper((key, index) => { let dummylet = map.get('' + key); dummylet; }));
  timer('Obj string key get took: ', () => looper((key, index) => { let dummylet = obj['' + key]; dummylet; }));
  timer('ray string key get took: ', () => looper((key, index) => { let dummylet = ray['' + key]; dummylet; }));
 }//#endregion

 console.log('\nEND')
}


const genCode = (f/*: Function*/) => `;(${f})();this.close()`

let code = genCode(TEST)

let blob = new Blob([code], { type: 'text/javascript' })
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

let myWorker = new Worker(url)
myWorker.onmessage = ({ data }) => console.log.apply(console, data)
myWorker.onerror = console.error
```

---

### ссылки на почитать

если есть желание дополнить раздел - воспользуйтесь кнопкой править.

- > [MDN Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
  >
  > Объект `Map` является простым ассоциативным массивом.
  >   **Любые типы** (как объекты, так и примитивы) могут быть использованы в качестве ключа или значения.
- > [learn.javascript.ru/set-map](https://learn.javascript.ru/set-map)
  >
  > **Set, Map, WeakSet и WeakMap**
  >
  > В ES-2015 появились новые типы коллекций в JavaScript:
  >   `Set`, `Map`, `WeakSet` и `WeakMap`.

Comment: Криво. Во-первых, только с Map ключ не конвертируется каждый раз из числа в строку. Во-вторых, ты в цикле вызываешь функцию - полагаю, тут начинает замеряться то, заинлайнится ли её вызов - если да, то будет быстро, а если нет - то медленно. Ну и ещё - доставаемое значение нигде не используется.