# Как оптимизировать проверку уникальности и обработку больших массивов с данными

Tags: javascript, node.js, циклы, оптимизация

Имеется 2 массива: `data_en` и `data_ru`

Каждый массив содержит примерно 20000-30000 JS объектов такого вида

```
{
  productId: 123456789
  productTitle: 'здесь какое то имя...'
}
```

**/* Дополнено */**

***Пример 2-х массивов:***

```
let data_en = [
 {productId: 1, productTitle: 'CaT CaT CaT CaT CaT'},
 {productId: 1, productTitle: 'CaT CaT CaT CaT CaT'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'DoG DoG DoG DoG'},
 {productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear'}, 
 {productId: 3, productTitle: 'FrOg FrOg FrOg FrOg FrOg'},
 {productId: 4, productTitle: 'Pen'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'DoG DoG DoG DoG'},
 {productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear'}
];



let data_ru = [
 {productId: 1, productTitle: 'КоТ КоТ КоТ КоТ КоТ'},
 {productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа'},
 {productId: 3, productTitle: 'лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа'},
 {productId: 4, productTitle: 'Ручка'},
 {productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш'},
 {productId: 7, productTitle: 'Кольцо'},
 {productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа'},
 {productId: 5, productTitle: 'Медведь'}
];
```

***Результат:***

```
[
  {
    productId: 1, 
    productTitle: 'cat cat cat cat cat', 
    productTitle_ru: 'кот кот кот кот кот'
  },
  {
    productId: 2, 
    productTitle: 'dog dog dog dog',
    productTitle_ru: 'собака собака собака собака'
  },
  {
    productId: 3, 
    productTitle: 'frog frog frog frog frog'
    productTitle_ru: 'лягушка лягушка лягушка лягушка лягушка'
  },
  {productId: 4, productTitle: 'pen',productTitle_ru: 'ручка'},
  {productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear', productTitle_ru: 'медведь'}, 
  {productId: 6, productTitle: '', productTitle_ru: 'карандаш'},
  {productId: 7, productTitle: '', productTitle_ru: 'кольцо'}
]
```

**/ * Конец дополнения */**

Причем в массиве data_en в свойстве объекта productTitle содержатся названия на английском языке (но не все, некоторая часть все же на русском)

Соответственно data_ru содержит объекты с свойством productTitle на русском языке.

Каждый из массивов `data_en`, `data_ru`  может содержать объект с `productId` который имеется в противоположно массиве, а может содержать такой которого в противоположном массиве нету. Более того каждый массив может содержать дубликаты объектов.

Для того чтобы оставить в каждом массиве только уникальные объекты я делаю так:

```
//Уникальные товары англ
let data_en_Unique = [];
let data_en_ids_Unique = [];
//Уникальные товары рус
let data_ru_Unique  = [];
let data_ids_ru_Unique = [];

//Проверяем англ на уникальность английского массива
data_en.forEach((v, i) => {
  //Если еще не проверяли этот товар то делаем это
  if(data_en_ids_Unique.indexOf(v.productId) == -1){
     //Если есть товар с русским именем кидаем его в русский массив
     if(v.productTitle.match(/([А-я].+)/)){
         arr_ru.push(v);
     }else{
         v.productTitle = v.productTitle.toLowerCase();
         //Добавляем в массив проверенных объектов 
         data_en_Unique.push(v);
         data_en_ids_Unique.push(v.productId);
     }
  }
});

//Проверка уникальности товаров в русском массиве
data_ru.forEach((v, i) => {
  if(data_ids_ru_Unique.indexOf(v.productId) == -1){
     v.productTitle = v.productTitle.toLowerCase();
     data_ru_Unique.push(v);
     data_ids_ru_Unique.push(v.productId);
  }
});
delete data_ids_ru_Unique;
delete data_ids_en_Unique;
```

На выходе я получаю 2 массива `data_en_Unique` и `data_ru_Unique` без повторяющихся объектов

Далее я делаю слияние данных объектов в один, но с именами на 2х языках

```
    //Слияние названий
    data_en_Unique.forEach((v, i) => {
        //Ищем объект с таким же ID в русском массиве 
        var TitleRu_obj = data_ru_Unique.filter(function(val) {
          return val.productId == v.productId;
        });
        //Если нашли русский аналог присваивает английскому товару русское название
        if(TitleRu_obj.length){
            v.productTitle_ru = TitleRu_obj[0].productTitle;
            //Удаляем русский аналог если нашли такой в английском массиве и добавили русское название в английский аналог
            data_ru_Unique.remove(TitleRu_obj[0]);
        }
    });
```

На выходе я получаю `data_ru_Unique` с именами на русском и на английском, но в `data_ru_Unique` остаются объекты `productId` которых может не присутствовать в `data_en_Unique` и их тоже нужно обработать и добавить в уже обработанный `data_en_Unique` (в котором уже объекты с русским и английским названием)

```
//Проходимся по оставшимся объектам и прописываем им что у них только русское имя
    data_ru_Unique.forEach((v, i) => {
      v.productTitle_ru = v.productTitle;
      v.productTitle = '';
    });
```

Далее массив с объектами только на русскои и массив с объектами на двух языках соедяняются воедино:

```
let all = data_en_Unique.concat(data_ru_Unique);
```

И делается еще один прогон для проверки на уникальность productID уже обединенных массивов

```
let Unique_finish = [];
let Unique_ids_ = [];

//Проверка уникальности после слияния
all.forEach((v, i) => {
  if(Unique_ids_.indexOf(v.productId) == -1){
         Unique_finish.push(v);
         Unique_ids_.push(v.productId);
  }
});
```

В итоге в массиве `all` оказываются объекты с названиями на 2-х языках, и объекты имеющие только русское название и только с уникальным `productId`

Собственно реально ли как то оптимизировать выполнение данных операций? Так как тут довольно большое кол-во циклов с перебором каждого из объектов, что довольно ресурсоемко и времязатратно

Comment: если в итоге сливаются все массивы, почему их не слить с самого начала? тем более в конце надо оставить только уникальные productId...

Comment: надо будет отличить массив с русскими и английскими названиями для прописывания русских названий в английские объекты, и все записи в английском которые содержат русские названия перенести в русский массив,  Ну .toLowerCase()  в принципе можно сделать только в самом конце.

Comment: т.е. получается там нет точного распределения, все в перемешку что-ли? надо было оставить пример 2-х  массивов буквально с 5-ю вариантами записей для примера, и что получить на выходе, так никто ничего не поймет

Comment: Добавьте характерный пример входных и ожидаемых выходных данных.

Comment: эмм, -- https://learn.javascript.ru/set-map  -- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890754/232932

Comment: а, да. а большие ли они, эти 20-30к

Comment: Полный объем обоих массивов вместе - 50-60 тыс объектов с 10 свойствами помимо этих 2х, после всех операцией остается около 22-36 тыс в зависимости от кол-ва входных. Примеры данных дополняю сейчас.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос примерами входных и ожидаемых данных. P.s 2 массива весят примерно 60 мб (еще другие свойства объектов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function merge(en, ru) {
  var r = {};
  en.forEach(i => (r[i.productId] || (r[i.productId] = {})).productTitle = i.productTitle);
  ru.forEach(i => (r[i.productId] || (r[i.productId] = {})).productTitle_ru = i.productTitle);
  var res = [];
  Object.keys(r).forEach(k => {
    var i = r[k];
    i.productId = +k;
    i.productTitle || (i.productTitle = '');
    i.productTitle_ru || (i.productTitle_ru = '');
    res.push(i);
  });
  return res;
}

let data_en = [
 {productId: 1, productTitle: 'CaT CaT CaT CaT CaT'},
 {productId: 1, productTitle: 'CaT CaT CaT CaT CaT'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'DoG DoG DoG DoG'},
 {productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear'}, 
 {productId: 3, productTitle: 'FrOg FrOg FrOg FrOg FrOg'},
 {productId: 4, productTitle: 'Pen'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'DoG DoG DoG DoG'},
 {productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear'}
];

let data_ru = [
 {productId: 1, productTitle: 'КоТ КоТ КоТ КоТ КоТ'},
 {productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа'},
 {productId: 3, productTitle: 'лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа'},
 {productId: 4, productTitle: 'Ручка'},
 {productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш'},
 {productId: 7, productTitle: 'Кольцо'},
 {productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш'},
 {productId: 2, productTitle: 'СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа'},
 {productId: 5, productTitle: 'Медведь'}
];

console.log(merge(data_en, data_ru));
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, но не упомянул что productId не обязательно что то вроде 1,2,3,4,5  и др он может быть и 1,2,3,8,10,33,100,1000 причем числа будут BigInt, моя ошибка..

Comment: @RedWoolf Ну и что? Вы запустили функцию со своими данными? Результат получили?

Comment: Не до конца разобрался в коде, да все работает, пока правда не прогонял на весь объем данных, но так все нормально, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
function merger(en, ru) {
  const complete = new Set()
  const replace = (v) => ((/[а-яё]/i.test(v.productTitle) ? ((v.productTitle_ru = v.productTitle), v.productTitle = '') : (v.productTitle_ru = '')), v)
  const add = (v, t) => v.productTitle_ru ?
    (t.productTitle && (v.productTitle = t.productTitle) && complete.add(v.productId)) :
    (t.productTitle_ru && (v.productTitle_ru = t.productTitle_ru) && complete.add(v.productId))
  return [...en.slice().concat(ru).reduce((a, v) => (
    (complete.has(v.productId) ||
      ((v = replace(Object.assign({}, v))),
        (a.has(v.productId) ? add(a.get(v.productId), v) : a.set(v.productId, v)))
    ), a
  ), new Map()).values()]
}

let arrEn = [
  { productId: 21, productTitle: 'АБВГД' },
  { productId: 21, productTitle: 'АБВГД' },
  { productId: 1, productTitle: 'CaT CaT CaT CaT CaT' },
  { productId: 1, productTitle: 'CaT CaT CaT CaT CaT' },
  { productId: 2, productTitle: 'DoG DoG DoG DoG' },
  { productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear' },
  { productId: 3, productTitle: 'FrOg FrOg FrOg FrOg FrOg' },
  { productId: 4, productTitle: 'Pen' },
  { productId: 2, productTitle: 'DoG DoG DoG DoG' },
  { productId: 5, productTitle: 'bear' }
];

let arrRu = [
  { productId: 20, productTitle: 'ABCDF' },
  { productId: 20, productTitle: 'ABCDF' },
  { productId: 1, productTitle: 'КоТ КоТ КоТ КоТ КоТ' },
  { productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш' },
  { productId: 2, productTitle: 'СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа' },
  { productId: 3, productTitle: 'лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа лягушКа' },
  { productId: 4, productTitle: 'Ручка' },
  { productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш' },
  { productId: 7, productTitle: 'Кольцо' },
  { productId: 6, productTitle: 'Карандаш' },
  { productId: 2, productTitle: 'СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа СобаКа' },
  { productId: 5, productTitle: 'Медведь' }
];

console.log(merger(arrEn, arrRu))
```